# Leaflet - Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, -0.3783868407297,43.304121626953)

Tags: javascript, object, leaflet, geojson, point

I'm trying to display small circles (or markers) on a map with leaflet from a geojson file.
It works with "MultiPolygon" geometry type but not with "Point" geometry type.
I don't understand why ?

````
// My GeoJson points
let Points = {"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"25","name":"Essai Point","activity":"WC","image":"image4.jpg"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[[-0.3783868407297,43.304121626953]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"27","name":"Essai Point2","activity":"WC","image":"image5.jpg"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[[-0.378387,43.30413]]}}]}

// My JavaScript code
let style = {  radius: 8,
               fillColor: "#ff7800",
               color: "#000",
               weight: 1,
               opacity: 1,
               fillOpacity: 0.8                    
             };

let circles = L.geoJson(Points, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
    }
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>```

// Console error
LatLng.js:32 
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, -0.3783868407297,43.304121626953)
    at new D (LatLng.js:32)
    at We (GeoJSON.js:235)
    at De (GeoJSON.js:186)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:117)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:107)
    at initialize (GeoJSON.js:92)
    at new i (Class.js:22)
    at Object.Ke (GeoJSON.js:439)
    at noelburos.php:116
````

Comment: A `Point` geometry in GeoJSON must be an array of two numbers, not an array of one element which is an array of two numbers. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.2

Comment: There are some GeoJSON linting tools available online to validate your data.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right.
The coordinate format in my GeoJSON file was wrong.
   For "Points" you only need 1 bracket [ ]:
"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [- 0.378387,43.30413]}
For "MultiPolygon" you need 4 brackets:
"Geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[- 0.37869579124434,43.304244638661], [- 0.37864922590826,43.304283484282], [- 0.37859357465296,43.304244638661], [- 0.37864695442846,43.304208272524], [- 0.37869579124434,43.304244638661]]]]}
It works perfectly and again thank you.